# NgRx and RxJS : Dependent State Selector

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, switchmap

I have a component that subscribes to multiple slices of state in the constructor.

```js
 @ViewChild(PComponent) PGrid: PComponent;

ngOnInit() {
    this.store.pipe(
          select(fromReports.getProcessState),
          takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
          .subscribe(selectedProcess=> {
            if (selectedProcess) {
              this.Data= selectedProcess.Data;
  }
          });

  this.store.pipe(
          select(fromReports.getProcessAnalysis),
          takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
          .subscribe(analysisData => {
            if (analysisData) {
              this.PGrid.LoadData(analysisData);
              }
          });
}
```

The first subscription subscribes to an array of objects while the second subscription calls a method in another component (@ViewChild(PComponent) PGrid). The `LoadData()` method in `PGrid` component depends upon this.Data from the first subscription.

When I run the code I get undefined for this. Data although there `selectedProcess.Data` has value

```js
this.store.pipe(
          select(fromReports.getProcessState),
          takeWhile(() => this.componentActive))
          .subscribe(selectedProcess=> {
            if (selectedProcess) {
              this.Data= selectedProcess.Data; //undefined

  }
          });
```

This means when the second slice of the state is subscribed and `LoadData()` method is called it errors out as `this.Data` is undefined.

I believe this is due to how Observable work and since they are async one function may not return the value before the other.

Que: 1 Why `this.Data= selectedProcess.Data;` sets `this.Data` to undefined even though  `selectedProcess.Data` has value

Que 2: I have looked at `flatMap` and `switchMap` but since I am new to RxJS and NgRx I am confused about how to leverage them. Any tips?

P.S On a similar note, I am subscribing to 2 slices separately in my `ngOnInit()`, is this a preferred way or should I combine them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is a stream.

Every observable stream should be named with a $.

Avoid using subscribe until the end.

[combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.

[tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) can be used for side effects and logging and does not affect the stream. It's the *"I don't know what I'm doing operator"*. I use it liberally.

*Pseudo code*

```
import { of, combineLatest } from "rxjs";
import { map, delay, tap, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

const DATA = "selectedProcessData";
const PROCESS_ANALYSIS = "analysis";

const service = {
  getData: () => {
    return of(DATA).pipe(delay(2000));
  },
  loadData: data => {
    return of(data).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
};
const store = {
  getProcessAnalysis: () => {
    return of(PROCESS_ANALYSIS).pipe(delay(2000));
  }
};

let getSelectedProcessData = null;
const getSelectedProcessData$ = service.getData().pipe(
  tap(data => console.log(`getSelectedProcessData::${data}`)),
  tap(data => (getSelectedProcessData = data))
); // mimick getting data from a service

const getAnalysisData$ = store.getProcessAnalysis(); // mimick selection of state

const loadAnalysisData$ = combineLatest(
  getSelectedProcessData$,
  getAnalysisData$
).pipe(
  tap(([getSelectedProcessData, getAnalysisData]) =>
    console.log(`combineLatest::${getSelectedProcessData}, ${getAnalysisData}`)
  ),
  map(([getSelectedProcessData, getAnalysisData]) => getAnalysisData),
  switchMap(getAnalysisData => service.loadData(getAnalysisData))
);

loadAnalysisData$.subscribe(loadedAnalysisData =>
  console.log(`loadedAnalysisData::${loadedAnalysisData}`)
);
```

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-mk1bfd)

Comment: Thanks, nicely explained. I did end up using combine latest but the way you explained in your example cleared it up for me.

Comment: @Abhi.Net did or did not? Thinking a bit more carefully I think [skipUntil](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/skipuntil) is better suited anyway

Comment: It did but I'll try skipUntil too. I have marked yours as an answer because it actually helped me understand the problem. RxJS and Observable can be tricky because you have to change your way of thinking..